# Difference between these two R functions

Tags: r

I am trying to illustrate the three types of extreme value distributions in $R$.

For type one, the distribution function is as follows.

$$
G(z) = \exp \left\{ -\exp \left[ -\left(\frac{z-b}{a}\right) \right] \right\}, z \in \mathbb R.
$$

In $R$ I wrote the following lines.

```
G1 <- function(z, a, b){
  x = (b-z)/a
  y = exp(-exp(x))
  y
}

G1(-3:3, 2, 3)
```

And I got what I intended, i.e., a finite sequence of numbers.

```
 [1] 1.89e-09 5.12e-06 6.18e-04 1.13e-02 6.60e-02 1.92e-01 3.68e-01
```

For type two, the distribution function is as follows.

$$
G(z) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 0, & z \leq b, \\[10pt] \exp\left[ -\left( \frac{z-b}{a} \right)^{-\alpha} \right], & z>b. \end{array} \right.
$$

In $R$ I wrote the following lines.

```
G2 <- function(z, a, b, alpha){
  if(z<b||z==b){
    0
  } else {
    x = -((z-b)/a)^{-alpha}
    y = exp(x)
    y
  }
}

G2(-3:3, 2, 3, 4)
```

***However, this time I only got one number.***

```
[1] 0
```

Where did I make a mistake in writing the second function G2, please? I want to have a finite sequence instead of just one number. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: Sorry. But I am afraid that I could not agree with you. As you can see, answers from stat.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com are different.

Comment: The difference in the answers doesn't matter.  The questions are the same. Please feel free to flag for moderator attention if you feel I've made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimately because `||` returns a length-one logical vector. If you feed a vector to it, it ignores everything except the first element. You can see what happens if you run your code one step at a time:

```
> z <- -3:3
> b <- 3
> z < b | z == b
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> z < b || z == b
[1] TRUE
```

Therefore, the code only evaluates `if(true)` and returns `0`. However, if you replace `||` by `|` it still won't work; now you will get the error message:

```
[1] 0
Warning message:
In if (z < b | z == b) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and you need to deal with the fact that the `if` function is not vectorized. As suggested by the other posters, you could define your function using something like this:

```
G2 <- function(z, a, b, alpha) ifelse(z <= b, 0, exp(-((z-b)/a)^-alpha))
```

Answer (score 1):

The data that you're sending in the function call to `G2` is your culprit.

You're stating if `z` is less than or equal to `b`, the output is 0. When calling G2, you're setting `z` to -3, -2 ... 2, 3, all of which are less than or equal to 3 (your `b` value).

When I run this I get a series:

```
> G2(-3:3, 2, -4, 4)
[1] 1.125352e-07 3.678794e-01 8.207548e-01 9.394131e-01 9.747249e-01 9.877302e-01
[7] 9.933583e-01
```

You can force the output of 7 zeros by placing an expression within the if statement:

```
G2 <- function(z, a, b, alpha){
  if(z<b||z==b){
    temp <- 0 * z
    temp
  } else {
    x = -((z-b)/a)^{-alpha}
    y = exp(x)
    y
  }
}
```

Now your call will output 7 zeros.

```
> G2(-3:3, 2, 3, 4)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: but still it should give 7 zeros instead of just 1.

Comment: I've updated the function with an expression which gets evaluated. Now your call will output 7 zeros.